# Perform bit manipulation to swap adjacent nibbles

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

In C language, how do I perform bit manipulation on `int` to swap adjacent [nibbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble)?

The input given to me is `0xDEAD` and the expected output is `0xEDDA`.

Comment: `if (input = 0xDEAD) { input = 0xEDDA; }`

Comment: What's the actual requirement? Are you swapping adjacent 4-bit groups?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full and complete assignment or exercise text. Copy-pasted as text. Also show us *your own* attempt, in the form of a [mre], and tell us about the problems you have with it.

Comment: @TobySpeight `input = 0xDEAD` -> `input == 0xDEAD`, but there is no bit manipulation in your comment :)

Comment: `input ^ 0x3377` ? We really don't have enough information about _how_ to treat the `input` so that XOR may be sufficient, although I think the problem has more information that you've given us.

Comment: It's not adjacent bits that are swapped.

Comment: @ouuan thanks for your answer, it works, can you explain your answer a little, coz I am clearly not much aware about what's happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call each 4-bit group a [nibble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble). Index the nibbles from right to left starting from 1. In the example `0xDEAD`, the nibble with index 1 is `D`, index 2 is `A`, index 3 is `E`, and index 4 is `D`.

Let's track where each nibble goes. The nibbles with odd indices go to the corresponding even indices, which is a nibble to the left. The nibbles with even indices go a nibble to the right.

Then we can pick each category of nibbles. The nibbles with odd indices can be picked with the bitmask `0x0f0f0f0f`, and the even ones can be picked with `0xf0f0f0f0`. Here we bitwise-and the input with the bitmask to pick the bits.

Then we can shift them by 4 bits (i.e. a nibble) to the left and to the right respectively and then bitwise-or them to get the answer.

The code is as follows:

```c
unsigned int swapAdjacentNibbles(unsigned int input)
{
    return ((input & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4) | ((input & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4);
}
```

Comment: can you explain working of your code.

Comment: @ruchi Please specify which part you cannot understand. What is it doing or why does it work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to knw what it is doing, thanks in advance:)

Comment: @ruchi: Do you know what the bit-shift operators `<<` and `>>` do? And do you know what bitwise AND `&` and bitwise OR `|` do?

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I read it but I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I guess that I'd better write some explanation besides the codes, but that's mentioned in only a single sentence in your link so I'm not sure. I'd quote this for you: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link"

Comment: @ruchi I added an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question by the way, it's clear that the high-rep users were never going to do that.